# How can I add 2d collision to the bottom of the obstacles in my game?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

The square ball will bounce off the top of the obstacles but it goes straight through them if it comes from the bottom. What can I add to the collision detection code to allow it to also check for collisions from the bottom. Thanks in advance. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Paddle Game</title>
    <style>
        * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Instructions</h1>
<p>Hit the square with the paddle at the bottom of the screen. You have 5 lives. If you hit the square you gain 1 point but if you miss you loose 1 life. If your lives fall below 0 you loose and the game restarts. Score 10 points to win.</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas; //This variable will be use as a reference to the canvas object
    var ctx; //A variable to hold the value of the context
    //Square Ball
    var rectX = 100;//rect X pos
    var rectY = 200;//rect Y pos
    var rectWidth = 25;//width
    var rectHeight = 25;//height
    var rectSpeedX = 10;
    var rectSpeedY = 10;
    //Paddle
    var rectX2 = 400;//rect X pos
    var rectY2 = 790;//rect Y pos
    var rectWidth2 = 100;//width
    var rectHeight2 = 20;//height
    //Obstruction
    var rectX3 = 500;
    var rectY3 = 600;
    var rectWidth3 = 300;
    var rectHeight3 = 25;
    //Obstruction
    var rectX4 = 200;
    var rectY4 = 300;
    var rectWidth4 = 300;
    var rectHeight4 = 25;

    var score = 0;
    var lives = 5;

    const WIDTH = 1000; //Width of the canvas
    const HEIGHT = 800; //Height of the canvas

    function mouseMove(event){
        rectX2 = rectX2 = event.pageX-((document.body.clientWidth-WIDTH)/2+ (rectWidth2/2));
    }
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);


    window.onload = function () {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var framesPerSecond = 30; //FPS
    setInterval(function(){
        drawEverything();//Calling the rect function 30 FPS
        movement();
        gameReset();
        winCondition();
    }, 1000/framesPerSecond); //Calls the move and draw function using an inline function. 30 FPS 1000/30

    }
    function drawEverything(){
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red' //Draws the white background every frame covering square
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH, HEIGHT); //background
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        ctx.fillRect(rectX, rectY, rectWidth, rectHeight); //redraws the recntangle each frame which gives the illusion of movement. moving square
        ctx.fillRect(rectX2, rectY2, rectWidth2, rectHeight2); //paddle
        ctx.fillRect(rectX3, rectY3, rectWidth3, rectHeight3); //obstruction
        ctx.fillRect(rectX4, rectY4, rectWidth4, rectHeight4) //obstruction
        ctx.fillText("Score", 100,50);
        ctx.fillText(score, 100,100); //score count
        ctx.fillText("Lives", 900,50);
        ctx.fillText(lives, 900,100); //life count
    }
    function movement(){
        rectX += rectSpeedX;
        rectY += rectSpeedY;

        if (rectX > WIDTH-12.5|| rectX < 0){
            rectSpeedX = -rectSpeedX;
        }
        if (rectY > HEIGHT-12.5 || rectY < 0){
            rectSpeedY = -rectSpeedY;
        }
        //console.log(rectX2);
        if(rectX < rectX2 + rectWidth2 && rectX + rectWidth > rectX2 && rectY < rectY2 + rectHeight2 && rectHeight + rectY > rectY2){
            //console.log("Hi")
            score += 1
            //rectSpeedX++
            //rectSpeedY++
            var deltaY = rectY
                                -(rectY+rectHeight2/2); 
                                rectSpeedY = deltaY * 2;
        } else if(rectY > HEIGHT-12.5){
            //console.log('Bye');
            lives -=1

        }
        if(rectX < rectX3 + rectWidth3 && rectX + rectWidth > rectX3 && rectY < rectY3 + rectHeight3 && rectHeight + rectY > rectY3){
          var deltaY = rectY
                                -(rectY+rectHeight3/2); 
                                rectSpeedY = deltaY * 2;  
        }
        if(rectX < rectX4 + rectWidth4 && rectX + rectWidth > rectX4 && rectY < rectY4 + rectHeight4 && rectHeight + rectY > rectY4){
          var deltaY = rectY
                                -(rectY+rectHeight4/2); 
                                rectSpeedY = deltaY * 2;  
        }
    }
    function gameReset(){
        if(lives < 0){
            alert("Game Over. Click Ok to restart. Remember do not let your lives fall below 0");
            location.reload();
        }
    }
    function winCondition(){
        if(score >= 10){
            alert("Congratulations you won! Hit 'OK' to restart the game.");
            location.reload();
        }
    }
   //if(rectX < rectX2 + rectWidth2 && rectX + rectWidth > rectX2 && rectY < rectY2 + rectHeight2 && rectHeight + rectY > rectY2)
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Also if you would like to tell me what you think about this program I would appreciate it I am more of a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have taken a look at your code...

You have made a good start on a game here, but there are couple of things that I think you should improve before taking it further. The main being that you need to go through your work and try to rewrite it using `objects`...

If you take a look at a similar html canvas bouncing ball thing I made [here](http://joeiddon.me/UltiBouncingBall/BallHtml.html), I think you would learn a lot from my code. You can see the source for that project on my github http://github.com/roadkillcat/UltiBouncingBall.

If you PM me, I can you write what you have so far more succinctly and make it easier to read. However, atm your code is too messy to make sense of and needs cleaning up. I would be happy to help if you want.

#### Here are some ideas to take the game further:

- make the ball a circle with the `arc` method
- stop the paddle being able to move off screen
- random positioning of the obstacles (rect3 + rect4) and of the ball

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried to implement some of your ideas. I have the rect's and ball position themselves randomly and the paddle sort of can not leave the screen if you test it you will see what I mean. I know there is a better way to do it. I tried changing the ball to a circle but the variables that make up the existing rectangle ball are crucial to the program. Where would you like me to PM you?

Comment: Create a github account and upload what you have their. If you then add me as a contributor then I can help you write it.

Comment: Okay I will. Thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: @Connor if you look on your github I have added an improved/ modified version... also if you go into settings on your repository and enable a thing called github pages then github will host the game for you...

Comment: I would like to thank you for taking the time to do this. I was never quite sure where I should use objects and arrays but they are more helpful than I thought they would be. I plan on making more simple things like this to try and better understand the language. For a lot of the code that has to do with shape dimensions I think if I draw it out I could better understand. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Keep going :) also you can vote up my answer to give me an extra couple of reputation points as that will help me on my way :p